# How to Structure E4X Syntax to handle Attributes?

Tags: actionscript-3, e4x

I'm using the weather.com XML web service to get the forecast high temp, low temp and icon.  The XML snippet is as follows:

```
<dayf>
<lsup>5/14/11 2:21 AM Local Time</lsup> 
<day d="0" t="Saturday" dt="May 14">
<hi>63</hi> 
<low>48</low> 
<sunr>6:39 AM</sunr> 
<suns>5:04 PM</suns> 
<part p="d">
<icon>32</icon>
```

I'm attempting to trace the above nodes and attributes using the following script snippet:

```
XML.ignoreWhitespace = true;
var urlLoader:URLLoader = event.currentTarget as URLLoader;
var resultXML:XML = XML(urlLoader.data);
trace(resultXML.dayf.day.hi);
trace(resultXML.dayf.day.low);
trace(resultXML.dayf.day.part.attribute("p=d").icon);

lbllowtemp.text= String(resultXML.dayf.day.low);
lblhitemp.text=String(resultXML.dayf.day.hi);
uicondicon.source=String(resultXML.dayf.day.part.attribute("p=d").icon)+".png";
```

However, when I run this script in my Flash application, I receive:

```
Error #2044: Unhandled ioError:. text=Error #2035: URL Not Found. URL: file:///C|/Documents/WeatherFLV/.png
```

So, the hi and low values are being read but the icon value in node part with attribute p=d is not working.

How should I modify my E4X syntax to obtain the icon node?

Thanks much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute name is `'p'` and not `'p=d'`, and the value of attribute `p` is `"d"`.
So you want to find the icon node within a `<part>` tag with an attribute `p` who has the value `"d"`.

`.(xxxxx)` will filter your XML with a given condition, here `@p` is the attribute

if you have only one part with such a value you can do:

```
resultXML.dayf.day.part.(@p=="d").icon
```

otherwise if you have multiple value you can get the first record:

```
resultXML.dayf.day.part.(@p=="d")[0].icon
```